# UITableView doesn't reload initially after typing in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

The problem is fairly weird, I try to fetch some data and then I reload data after getting them. I type in `searchbar` the first letter and it doesn't reload the data in `UITableview` but when the `searchText` gets edited the next time the `UITableView` gets reloaded from itself *immediately*.

I looked at many solutions with no gain.

Both delegates are set in Storyboard.

Here is my code:

```
extension SearchVC: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        reload(searchText) { (users) in
            self.queriedUsers = users
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Table view reloading \(self.queriedUsers.count)")
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension SearchVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: queriedCellID, for: indexPath) as! QueriedUserViewCell
        cell.nicknameLabel.text = queriedUsers[indexPath.row].getNickname()
        cell.usernameLabel.text = queriedUsers[indexPath.row].getName()
        cell.userProfilePicture.image = UIImage(named: "defaultpfp")
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return queriedUsers.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make sure that you are getting the results from your reload method

Comment: Yes, the print method tells me there is indeed some data before reloading.